# Type mismatch: cannot convert from <ObjectTypeX> to <ObjectTypeX> in Tomcat7/Java 1.7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, type-mismatch

I'm encountering a strange error on the following line:

```
ArrayList<BlastHit> filtered = new ArrayList<BlastHit>();
```

...where BlastHit is a class I have written.

This is in a .jsp file, executed by Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu, with Java 1.7.

The full stacktrace is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 26 in the jsp file: /results.jsp
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.ArrayList<BlastHit> to java.util.ArrayList<BlastHit>
23: ArrayList<BlastHit> filtered = new ArrayList<BlastHit>();
24: try {
25:     blastResults = new BlastResults(json);
26:     filtered = Blast.filterBySpecies(blastResults.getHits(), request.getParameterValues("species"));
27: } catch (Exception e) {
28:     blastResults = new BlastResults();
29:     filtered = new ArrayList<BlastHit>();


An error occurred at line: 58 in the jsp file: /results.jsp
The method makeHitHTML(BlastHit) in the type Blast is not applicable for the arguments (BlastHit)
55:             out.println("No hits found");
56:         }
57:         for (int i = 0; i < filtered.size(); i++) {
58:             out.println(Blast.makeHitHTML((BlastHit)filtered.get(i)));
59:         }
60:     }
61:     %>


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Isn't it essentially telling me that it can't convert from type `BlastHit` to type `BlastHit`? They're the same class! What's going on here?

I've probably omitted some vital piece of data, so feel free to ask me for more information.

Thanks a lot.

P.S. I appreciate you're not really supposed to write scriptlets in JSP pages these days but... well, one problem at a time.

EDIT: I appreciate the error message says the problem is on line 26, but if you remove this it then has a problem with the `ArrayList<BlastHit> filtered = new ArrayList<BlastHit>();` line.

Comment: what returns `Blast.filterBySpecies()` method? as you can see in your stacktrace, there is the error...

Comment: somehow it seems that you have 2 different definitions of `BlastHit` in your code. Could it be, that you define it in .jsp and maybe import it from somewhere else? Try to write full class-name of `BlastHit` in your code

Comment: I import it at the top of the JSP file, and I definitely don't define it within the JSP file - I agree that two different definitions of BlastHit would cause this but I cannot for the life of me work out where the two definitions are. The class is saved in WEB-INF/classes/<package-dirs>/BlastHit.class

Comment: Blast.filterBySpecies() returns an ArrayList<BlastHit> object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that
1. There are not two classes with the same name but in different packages. You can try to prefix them with the package in the test.
2. There might be two different definitions of the same class in the same package but comming from different sources (jars) or in different classloaders(since you're playing with tomcat).

You could try to write identical code in a normal class and see if it works.

Comment: Agree with this presumed diagnose. +1